# Vee validate multiple validation

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I've created custom rule using extend from `vee-validate`. so i've this `rules`

```
required|numeric|min_value:1|lte:@max_quantity|lte:@stock
```

from above code when `lte:@max_quantity` is **false** and `lte:@stock` is **true** it get override by the last rule so the result always considered as **true** instead of **false**

so how can i achieve this?

**rules:**

```
extend("gte", {
  params: ["target"],
  validate(value, { target }) {
    return value >= target;
  },
  message: "{_field_} greater than or equal to {target}"
});

extend("lte", {
  params: ["target"],
  validate(value, { target }) {
    return value <= target;
  },
  message: "{_field_} less than or equal to {target}"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle this you could create a custom rule that accepts [multiple arguments](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/basics.html#rule-arguments) `@max_quantity` and `@stock`, and computes the result taking both into consideration. Then specify that custom rule name instead of `lte`.